# Is there any advantage in having staff that used to play at the club?

Tags: football-manager-2013

Assuming two members of staff have the same staff attributes, if one of them was a player at the club for a long time before becoming a coach, will they be more effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will have better club knowledge, so any reports they provide (including comments in backroom meetings) will be more reliable. Their loyalty will probably also be higher, meaning better morale and possibly lower salary demands.